# Point location in tetrahedron meshes

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Are there any proven data structures for point location in tetrahedron meshes where the tetrahedra are all disjoint but are "touching" each other? I.e. most faces are faces of exactly two tetrahedra.

By locationI mean that I want to find out in which of the tetrahedrons a given point is located, or if it is not located in any.

So far, I have tried:

1. A simple KD-Tree. This was way too slow for my needs, as the average tree depth was very high and I still had a lot of individual tetrahedrons to test in each leaf.
2. A grid which contained all the intersecting tetrahedra for each cell. This seems to work a lot better, but was still not fast enough. First, the grid contained a lot of empty cells because my overall mesh is not very "boxy". Second, most cells that actually did contain tetrahedra, did contain a lot of them (10+). I suppose this is because a lot of tetrahedra share every vertex, and as soon as a vertex is in a cell, all its adjacent tetrahedra are too.

Some further information on the input data: The mesh is usually not convex and may have holes or inclusions. Though the last two are somewhat unlikely, i have to deal with them, which makes "walking" impossible without (expensive and complicated?) preprocessing.

Comment: Have you tries the following (could not find a reference, so I describe it shortly)? Start in an arbitrary tet. Determine a face, relatively to which the point lies outside of the tet (on the opposite side than the fourth tet vertex). Step on the the tet on the other side of the face. Check again. If there is no such face, the point is in the current tet. This algorithm works for convex meshes. Does it fit your needs?

Comment: Another thought about that. You can combine the two methods. After finding the correct grid cell, you can look for the correct tet with the method above.

Comment: That sounds neat. Surely, you can make it work for non convex meshes by filling concavities with "void" tetrahedra?

Comment: Probably, although it could be difficult to fill the holes. But give it a try, if you like.

Comment: Maybe [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), in your case, locates smaller number of tetrahedrons to test. Depth is probably like in KD-Tree.

Comment: I don't know what your application is, and what level of guarantees you need to be able to make, but there are some approximate search techniques which can operate very quickly, and which have good implementations available.

In particular, I would look at [FLANN](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN), which is a library for approximate nearest-neighbor searches which has received quite a bit of optimization and performance attention.

This will only perform the nearest-point search, but I thought this would be good to point to as a significant improvement over KD-trees.

Comment: @Eric: what does approximate mean in this context? will arbitrarily not detect the right tetrahedron or will it be "fuzzy" around the edges?

Comment: Basically, it means there's a chance you will find the second-closest instead of closest point.  FLANN has an adjustable parameter (target accuracy) to control the speed / accuracy tradeoff.  You can also check out the [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) library if you want, which has efficient implemntations of both approximate and exact nearest-neighbor search.

Answer (score 6):

If you are dealing with a 3D triangulation composed of tetrahedrons with adjacency information, you can just use **walking**. This is a standard technique for point location and uses 3D **orientation tests**.

For more information see the paper **Walking in a triangulation** by Olivier Devillers et al. (Google it and you will find a PDF of it.)

Answer (score 1):

Some quick thoughts: an octree will be similar to your grid approach, but allow you to quickly ignore empty grids, and to subdivide grids which are too full.

Also, you don't mention how you're testing if a point lies inside of a tetrahedron. It's been a while since I've looked at it, but perhaps [barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system_%28mathematics%29#Barycentric_coordinates_on_tetrahedra) could speed up your point-in-tetrahedron tests? Or a [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) to quickly exclude tetrahedra based on tetrahedron vertices which are clearly on the wrong side of the sweep line to contain the point.

Comment: I'm using barycentric coordinates already. How exactly would you apply a sweep line here?

Comment: One simple method would be to sort points on their x-coordinate. Any tetrahedron whose points all have x-coordinates less than the x-coordinate of the point you're interested in (similarly, all greater than) couldn't be the tetrahedron you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This is admittedly a little brainstormy.

Perhaps a custom of a kdTree that uses face-aligned planes instead of axis-aligned ones.

If a point is on the "correct" side of all four planes of a tetrahedron, then it must be inside the tetrahedron.  (Right?)  And if you're on the wrong side of any plane, then you can not only rule out the current tet, but also any others on that side of the plane.

It seems you should be able to build a tree where each node is a single plane, and a leaf node means you're in one specific tet (assuming the tets never intersect).  The tree may be deep, but since each test is only against a plane (rather than a more expensive triangle test) and since a leaf node gives you exactly one answer, it seems like it should be fast.

Building the tree efficiently may prove difficult.

Comment: Isn't that just an ordinary BSP tree then? Lots of splitting or duplicating would have to happen

Comment: @ltjax:  No, it's not an ordinary BSP.  With an ordinary BSP tree, you traverse to a leaf that gives you a list of tets to test.  With the approach I'm trying to describe, traversing the tree to a leat gives you a specific tet that the point is in or an indication that the point is not in any tet.  It's combining the partitioning with the testing against a tet.

Comment: That's still pretty ordinary. I assume the amount of duplication and the average tree depth make this unfeasible though. Remember that if you split a tetrahedron, you might end up with up to six tetrahedra. And you will get lots of accuracy problems building the tree unless you use something more "orthogonal" like a KD-Tree or an Octree.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment about splitting a tetrahedra.  These wouldn't be arbitrary planes, but the same planes that contain the sides of tetrahedra themselves.  There wouldn't be splitting involved.  Each branch down the tree effectively rules out tets that are completely on the other side of the test plane.  No splitting required.

Comment: What about tetrahedra that are on both sides of a selected plane?